# WCF REST complex out parameters

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I'm trying to do the following:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
int Create(string key, out IEnumerable<SomeClass> items);
```

And it "works", but the behavior is that each "SomeClass" is serialized as XML, not JSON.
I'd like to have them formatted as JSON along with the everything else.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add RequestFormat as well?

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
```

Comment: I have, to no avail.  I will double-check it just to be sure.

Comment: Double-checked.  Still coming back XML

Answer (score 1):

This might happen because you might have exculded the Factory attribute in the Service markup.
Try Adding this :

```
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
```